# sqlite transactions do not respect delete

Tags: sqlite

I need to modify all the content in a table. So I wrap the modifications inside a transaction to ensure either all the operations succeed, or none do.  I start the modifications with a DELETE statement, followed by INSERTs. What I’ve discovered is even if an INSERT fails, the DELETE has still takes place, and the database is not rolled back to the pre-transaction state.

I’ve created an example to demonstrate this issue. Put the following commands into a script called EXAMPLE.SQL

```
CREATE TABLE A(id INT PRIMARY KEY, val TEXT);

INSERT INTO A VALUES(1, “hello”);

BEGIN;
     DELETE FROM A;
     INSERT INTO A VALUES(1, “goodbye”);  
     INSERT INTO A VALUES(1, “world”);
COMMIT;

     SELECT * FROM A;
```

If you run the script: “sqlite3 a.db < EXAMPLE.SQL”, you will see:

```
SQL error near line 10: column id is not unique
1|goodbye
```

What’s surprising is that the SELECT statement results did not show ‘1|hello’.

It would appear the DELETE was successful, and the first INSERT was successful. But when the second INSERT failed (as it was intended to)….it did not ROLLBACK the database.

Is this a sqlite error? Or an error in my understanding of what is supposed to happen?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works as it should.

`COMMIT` commits all operations in the transaction. The one involving `world` had problems so it was not included in the transaction.

To cancel the transaction, use `ROLLBACK`, not `COMMIT`. There is no automatic `ROLLBACK` unless you specify it as conflict resolution with e.g. `INSERT OR ROLLBACK INTO ...`.

And use `'` single quotes instead of `“` for string literals.

Comment: Spot on. Thanks. FYI -- I was using the sqlite command shell as a proof of concept. The actual solution will be in code, in which case we would obviously do the rollback. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

[This documentation](http://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html) shows the error types that lead to an automatic rollback:

```
SQLITE_FULL: database or disk full
SQLITE_IOERR: disk I/O error
SQLITE_BUSY: database in use by another process
SQLITE_NOMEM: out or memory
SQLITE_INTERRUPT: processing interrupted by application request
```

For other error types you will need to catch the error and rollback, more on this is covered in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308272/error-handling-and-rollback-transaction-in-sqlite-from-sql-statement).