# Rollback SQLite transaction operations in case of failure

Tags: sqlite, transactions

How can I rewrite my transaction to undo changes since the beginning whenever an error condition occurs before the end?

I see this question [has already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308272/error-handling-and-rollback-transaction-in-sqlite-from-sql-statement) and I followed the link provided in that answer. It's not clear to me what the next step is. I am hoping someone can illustrate the solution with an example applied to this transaction:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO Employee(ID, Name) VALUES(1, 'John');
...
<some failure happens here>
...
END TRANSACTION;
```

In this case, I would like the insert into the Employee table to be undone because a failure occurs before `END TRANSACTION`. How do I write rules that enforce this? This is for sqlite version 3.9.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute a [`ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` query](http://sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html), or use the [`ON CONFLICT ROLLBACK` conflict resolution](http://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) on the failable queries to let SQLite roll back the transaction for you.